# Why GEE can have only one task is described as "Running on server", but tasks are described as"Submitted to server"?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Some time ago, when I was experimenting with my graduation thesis, I needed to download Landsat8 images in batches. At that time, 6 tasks could be described as "Running on server". But now only one task can be exported to my driver, which greatly reduces my work efficiency. How can this be solved?

[image]